# Is Reiko Sakakibara's aunt really her relative?

Tags: another

Given that the Extra was

> Sakakibara's Aunt Reiko Mikami, who was also the assistant homeroom teacher,

and that

> everyone's memories and official records are altered.

Is Reiko really related to Sakakibara or was

> that a lie fabricated to account for her existence?

Comment: i don't think anyone can answer this, maybe not even the officials did think about this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reiko Mikami](http://another.wikia.com/wiki/Reiko_Mikami) is the younger sister of Ritsuko Sakakibara (mother of Kouichi), so she really is his relative.

> She is the extra because she died once before, which pretty much proves she existed.

Another proof of her being Kouichi's aunt is

> Rei, the parrot she hates, was bought by her father after her death and was named after her.

You can also see her flashbacks from when she was a student in the manga.